How can I train an LSTM Autoencoder for each iteration of training with each dataset?
I’ve been trying to build and train an LSTM Autoencoder. While the reference that I was using trained the model only once, I added a function to run the training multiple times if each iteration of training for each dataset ended.
Still, I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track or not. It slightly feels like there are some possibilities that my code is overwriting the trained model on each iteration.
Is the Python code below actually training the model for each iteration of training with each dataset (There are 75 CSV files to use for training this model)?
The following is the python code that I added for building and training the model inside a single function (trainModel()).
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, RepeatVector, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


# The LSTM network takes the input in the form of subsequences of equal intervals of input shape (n_sample,n_timesteps,features).
# We will use the below custom function to create these sequences
def create_sequences(X, y, time_steps=1):
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
        v = X.iloc[i:(i + time_steps)].values
        Xs.append(v)
        ys.append(y.iloc[i + time_steps])
    return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)


def trainModel():
  for i in range(75):
    fileList = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/fileList.csv")
    filename = fileList.iloc[i, 0]
    temp = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/dataFolder/"+filename+".csv")
    train_size = int(len(temp[["time_abs(%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f)", "velocity(m/s)"]]))
    train = df.iloc[0:train_size]


    # Normalizing the data
    scalar = StandardScaler()
    scalar = scalar.fit(train[['velocity(m/s)']])

    train['velocity(m/s)'] = scalar.transform(train[['velocity(m/s)']])

    time_steps = 30

    X_train, y_train = create_sequences(train[['velocity(m/s)']],train['velocity(m/s)'],time_steps)


    # Build an LSTM Autoencoder

    # An autoencoder is a neural network model that seeks to learn a compressed representation of an input.
    # They are trained using supervised learning methods, referred to as self-supervised.

    # In this architecture, an encoder LSTM model reads the input sequence step-by-step. 
    # After reading in the entire input sequence, the hidden state or output of this model represents
    # an internal learned representation of the entire input sequence as a fixed-length vector.
    # This vector is then provided as an input to the decoder model that interprets it as each step
    # in the output sequence is generated.

    timesteps = X_train.shape[1]
    num_features = X_train.shape[2]


    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(timesteps,num_features)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(RepeatVector(timesteps)) # Repeats the input n times.
    model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(num_features))) # apply a layer to every temporal slice of an input.

    model.compile(loss='mae',optimizer='adam')


    # Train the Autoencoder
    early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=3,mode='min') # if the monitored metric does not change wrt to the mode applied for 3 epochs, stop training
    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=32,validation_split=0.1,callbacks=[early_stop],shuffle=False)

    model.save('anomaly_model.h5', overwrite=False)
    model.save('anomaly_model_'+ i +'.h5')

